# Calculating percentage of area from polygons inside one polygon in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, area, calculate-values

I need to calculate percentage of different areas contained in one Cadastral parcel.
Every parcel (polygon) is overlapped with one or more polygons. I need to find percentage of every overlapping polygon inside parcel. I have used intersect command to get intersected polygons (attribute table on image below).

How can I group values by one attribute so I can later calculate percentage of areas in another field?

[image]

[image]

How can I group values by one attribute (BROJ_KC) to get something like this (green part of table)?:

[image]

Comment: Use Summary Statistics.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I can't get what I want. Whi

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Statistic field: FID_KAT_CESTICA, type: COUNT, Case field: NAMJENA1, Shape_Area

Comment: I have tried many combinations of variables in this command bu could not get results that would put all intersected data and their areas in one row. Maybe you could give me example? Maybe Tabulate Intersection is better solution?

Comment: I was only viewing your picture on my phone previously and it looks Summary Statistics alone will not be able to do this after all.  The way I would do it is to use a combination of Summary Statistics, arcpy.da.SearchCursor() and TableToExcel.

Comment: For now, only solution is to export table to excel, use power pivot to rearrange data and join it back with ArcMap... my arcpy knowledge is too week...